# js adding a value to a element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found some answers to similiar questions but I'm still not getting it.

but I hope it's a short problem so I dont make too much trouble! ;-)

I have a js array

```
arr = [ a, b, c]
```

How can i add value to this elements dynamically? For example I want that each element get the value `true`

So it should look like this afterwards:

```
arr = [ a = true, b = true, c = true];
```

I tried the following: (using jquery framework)

```
$.each(arr, function(i){
                arr[i] = true;
            });
```

but then I just get

```
arr = [ true, true, true]
```

hope someone can help me!
thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr = [ a = true, b = true, c = true];
```

That's a different type of data structure you're looking for: not an array, but a mapping. (PHP makes arrays and mappings the same datatype, but that's an unusual quirk.)

There's not quite a general-purpose mapping in JavaScript, but as long as you're using strings for keys and you take care to avoid some of the built-in JavaScript Object member names, you can use an Object for it:

```
var map= {'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true};
alert(map['a']); // true
alert(map.a); // true
```

ETA:

> if i have an array how can i make it to look like ["required": true, "checklength": true]?

```
var array= ['required', 'checklength'];

var mapping= {};
for (var i= array.length; i-->0;) {
    var key= array[i];
    mapping[key]= true;
}

alert(mapping.required); // true
alert('required' in mapping); // also true
alert('potato' in mapping); // false
```

Comment: For the benefit of the OP and other novices, please note that using this method, there is no `length` property as you are accustomed to with normal, indexed arrays.  Also, iteration over this data type must be done using `for..in` (http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_loop_for_in.asp), as opposed to an array which should be iterated over using the standard `for` structure (http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: hey. thank you but i still dont know how to add an value to a element as i descriped above. u just show me how to set up a object with value direct ..but if i have an array (or object... ) so  ["required", "checklength"] (firebug) how can i make it to look like  ["required": true, "checklength": true]? maybe my english isnt good enough to descripe it clearly! :-(

Comment: An array in JS with named keys is an object. He answered your question.